# How to filter for multiple values within a long list of JSON data in JS?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of multiple items in JSON that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    IsValid: true, 
    forSale: false,
    Color: red,
    value: 22
  },
  {
    IsValid: false, 
    forSale: true,
    Color: blue,
    value: 123
  }
]
```

A user will then select filters to search through the list such as:

```
[color: red, forSale: true, value over 10]
```

What is the easiest way to filter through the JSON **for multiple values?**

I tried having the filtered options as an object like:

```
{forSale: true, color: blue}
```

Then doing a `forEach` of the JSON, with a nested `Object.map` of the filtered options, but if there are two or more items the Object.mapping doesn't return the right results.

How would you filter through a long list of items in JSON, for multiple options?

Comment: You don't have JSON data. On a _very_ important technical point: "JSON" is the string-serialied form of data. It is nothing until you parse it. You can't `forEach` it, you can't `Object.map` it, you have to parse it first, at which point it _stops_ being JSON and becomes a regular JS array of regular JS objects, and so your question is really about how to filter an array of plain objects using multiple key/values, and that already has answers on SO, and the web at large.

Comment: Okay, fair enough - you are right its not JSON. As for the answer - I  looked and I found using nested object.map within forEach and it wasn't properly returning what I needed so since I've been struggling with it all day and couldn't find anything I asked. Do you have a link you can provide or a suggestion?

Comment: "Data" doesn't tell anyone what you're dealing with: you have an array of plain objects.

Comment: The only difference versus the dupe target is you'll need to manually compare the "value over 10" using a conditional.

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen I've give it a go! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const filters = [{label: 'forSale', value: false}, {label: 'color', value: 'red'}];
const filteredArray = array.filter(item => filters.every(filter => item[filter.label] === filter.value))
```

or

```
const filters = {forSale: true, color: 'blue'}; 
const filteredArray = array.filter(item => {
    let result = true;
    for(let key in filters) {
        if (item[key] !== filters[key]){
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
})
```

or

```
const filters = {forSale: true, color: 'blue'};
const filteredArray = array.filter(item => Object.keys(filters).every(key => item[key] === filters[key]))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Right idea, but I think OP wants "value over 10" rather than "value exactly 10", where 10 can be any number. Good answers usually offer some explanation and maybe links to docs for the funcs you're using. Also, this particular question is a fairly definitive dupe, so it's usually closed out as such to keep information in one place.

Comment: I could run another check for the values within the returned results for if its over 10, although I'm sure there is a better way